# PowerShell Import-Module SqlServer - why are "push" and "pop" location required?

Tags: powershell

I am executing a PowerShell script which executes a SQL query. Script is run from the location where my script is installed.

If I do not put `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` my script will not work. Why is that?

```
push-location
Import-Module SqlServer
pop-location
    
$SQL_SERVER_NAME="LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS"
$DB_ADMIN_USER="sa"
$DB_ADMIN_PASS="test"
$DB_INSTANCE_NAME="ARENA"
   
$query =@"
..................    
GO
"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_NAME -Username $DB_ADMIN_USER -Password
```

This code works completely, I am just interested why this is needed. I cannot conclude anything from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Absolutely is not needed and as they are in the script there, do nothing at all.  You are saying that if you remove both lines the script does not work?  What is the error that you get, if any?

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, can you provide the error? Also, can you run `$env:PSModulePath -split -';' | clip` and paste the output here? (`| clip` will pipe the resulting output to the clipboard and can be pasted). In absence of the error, my thought is that the `SqlServer` module location is not defined on the `PSModulePath` with an absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see `push-location` and `pop-location` used like this for older `SqlServer` modules because it was a [common workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5jkdjl/sqlps_module_and_working_directory/). The issue was that when importing the module it would change your working directory, for example

```
PS C:\> Import-Module SQLPS

PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

So, a push and pop was used to ensure your working directory remains unchanged when importing.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting indeed. +1